# FieldInfo.SetValue(): Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

Program Logic:

- Define some default values for an `Employee` in the C# program
- Read an XML file about different Employees
- Use `Reflections` to go through all the fields of the `DefaultAttributes` class
- If a field name is present as an attribute in an Employee's XML node then, override the default value with the attribute value

**Employee DefaultAttributes Class**

```
public class DefaultAttributes
{
    public string EmployeeName = "XYZ";
    public int[] ProjectCodes = new int[] { 1, 1 };
    public string city = "Munich";
}
```

**XML File:**

```
   <TopNode Id="A">
      <MiddleNode EmployeeName="John">
         <InnerMostNode Age="46" Average="88.15" ProjectCodes="46 112" City="Berlin">            
         </InnerMostNode>
      </MiddleNode>
      <MiddleNode EmployeeName="Claudia">
         <InnerMostNode Age="50" Average="96.58" ProjectCodes="9 510">            
         </InnerMostNode>
      </MiddleNode>
   </TopNode>
```

**Use of Reflections To Override Default Values:**

```
    private void OverrideAttribites(XmlNode xmlNode, DefaultAttributes nodeAttributes)
    {
        //Traverse through all fileds of DefaultAttributes class
        FieldInfo[] fieldsOfDefaultAttributesclass = typeof(DefaultAttributes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var field in fieldsOfDefaultAttributesclass)
        {
            // Check if the "field" is present in the attributes of the current XML node
            string fieldName = field.Name;
            if (xmlNode.Attributes[fieldName] is not null) //i.e. field is present in the Attributes list
            {
                var attValue = xmlNode.Attributes[fieldName].Value;

                if (attValue.Contains(' ')) //i.e. attribute value should be stored in an array type
                {
                    if (!fieldName.Contains('['))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Field type is not an array type but the XML attribute value contains an array");
                    }

                    //Set Array Value
                }
                else
                {
                    //PROBLEM: THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION !!!!!
                    field.SetValue(nodeAttributes, xmlNode.Attributes[fieldName].Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question:** The attributes values in my XML file are present `string` format. How do I use the attribute's value to set a field's value in a generic way (`field` could be `int`, `double`, `int[]` etc.)?

Comment: Check field.FieldType and then Convert your string to that Type.

Comment: @Ralf: I already thought about using `field.FieldType` but then I will have to handle the case of each DataType separately. Isn't there any more straightforward way to do it?

Comment: But you should know that a specific field of the XML (so a specific type of data) goes to a specific field of the Employee class... So the code cannot be generic and the data type validation is an added values here

Comment: Not really. There is no generic sourcetype to targettype conversion here possible. And when looking at  ProjectCodes thats a pretty custom string to int[] thing that needs to be explicitly programmed.

Comment: While implementing Convert.ChangeType might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0

Comment: @skm - *Isn't there any more straightforward way to do it?* - yes, deserialize using [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization) instead of manually parsing.